# change permissions with find for specific files

Tags: bash, find, chmod

Let's say I have a directory called permissions, that contains several files with different access rights.

What I want to do is if a file has access rights for `others` category, I want to accord the same access rights for the `group` category.

example1:
if file_1 has `r-x---r--`, then I want that file to have the permissions `r-xr--r--`

example2:

file_2 has `r-xr----x` rights, I want it to become `r-xr-x--x`

example3:

file_3 and file_4 have `rw---x---` and `rwxr-----` access respectively, these files should stay unchanged

I know with `find` I can search for such files with `-perm 0740` then `-exec chomd --- \;` to change their value, but how to search only the files that have `other` permissions different than `group` permission, and when found, change their `group`  access rights to match `other` rights

Comment: You can find files with `other` permissions by `find . -perm /o=rwx`. You need a script after `-exec` to perform the correct `chmod`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chmod` can do this by itself](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html):

```
chmod -R g+o dir
```

> A  combination  of  the letters `ugoa` controls which users' access to the file will be changed: [...] other users in the file's group (g), [...]
>
> The operator + causes the selected file mode bits to be added to the existing file mode bits of each file [...]
>
> The letters `rwxXst` select file mode bits for the affected users [...] Instead of one or more of  these  letters,
> you  can specify exactly one of the letters `ugo`: [...] and the permissions granted to users that are in neither of the two preceding categories (o).

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `find` and a loop, you could search for each of the `r` `w` `x` permissions which is not set for the `group`, but set for `others` and set it for `group`:

```
for perm in r w x; do
  find . -type f \! -perm /g+"$perm" -perm /o+"$perm" -exec chmod g+"$perm" {} \;
done
```